# Memory not releasing .Net Application

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, garbage-collection

I had a list of objects. The count of objects in the list is approx 5,06,011.

And it consuming 190MB in ram.

After some time I don't need that list. I cleared the list

list.clear() command clears all objects from that list.

But still, my application consuming 190 MB in ram.

How to dispose the list properly?

```
public class FileProperty
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string DirectoryPath { get; set; }
        public long LastWriteTime { get; set; }
        public long Size { get; set; }
    }

void Main()
{
   var Sqlite = new SqliteConnection(@"Filename=D:\Work\UserData.db");
   var FileProps=Sqlite.Query<FileProperty>("SELECT *FROM FileProperties;").ToList();

   //Task completed with that collection
   //Now want to free memory
   FileProps.Clear();
   //But memory not freed
}
```

Comment: How did you check (which tool; which metric)? How long did you wait for GC to occur? A list itself uses only little RAM. Are those objects referenced by something else? Best use a .NET memory profiler such as dotMemory (part of Resharper).

Comment: The metric part is really important, because .NET does not give the memory back to the operating system. So it depends on the perspective: from OS point of view, the memory is gone (it has given to .NET). From .NET point of view, the memory is empty (no objects inside).

Comment: I waited for 5 minutes.
Is there any way to force Garbage Collector to free up resources.

Comment: I find the combination of `GC.Collect(); Thread.Sleep(1);` is quite reliable. The `Thread.Sleep()` ensures that the OS can make a context switch to the GC thread.

Comment: post some code!

Comment: If you can't afford a memory profiler, there is also [tag:windbg], a free but hard to learn debugger, which can tell you about the object count.

Comment: Little Code added @sommmen

Comment: Little code added @ThomasWeller

Comment: When do you see the 20MB spike? After which line?

Comment: @asaf92 After 2nd line in Main function

Comment: Break the second line to two lines where the second one is the `ToList` call. Does the memory spike after the first or second line?

Comment: @asaf92
var FileProps=Sqlite.Query<FileProperty>("SELECT *FROM FileProperties;").ToList();

Comment: I meant break it in code and debug where exactly is the memory spike

Comment: @asaf92 After execution of second line memory spiking

Comment: Are you running a debug build or a release build?

Comment: Maybe Sqlite is holding references to the objects you created preventing them from being released? Try to generate the list in a different function to make sure the Sqlite reference goes out of scope

Comment: @ThomasWeller running in Debug Build
 Tried with the different table in database 5,06,011 object references in the list Consuming approx 195 MegaBytes

Answer (score 1):

list.Clear() will not reset the capacity of the list that has already been allocated. Even after calling Clear(), the capacity remains same as before, meaning that the underlying array is not yet destroyed.

Calling TrimExcess() after Clear() will reset the capacity which might eventually free the memory.

But, once the object is not referenced by any other data structure, it should be eligible for garbage collection by default.

Comment: Same problem, memory not freed after TrimExcess() also.
Observing memory size consuming by application in Task Manager and also in VS Diagnostic Tool

Comment: An array of 20.000 pointers to objects is just ~400kB, not 20MB.

Comment: @Varun: Task Manager is one of the worst tools for measuring memory. What memory do you look for in Task Manager? You need to understand what "Working set" means. Working set is not the correct thing to look at in >90% of the cases. In fact, it never was the last 13 years of my life.

Comment: @ThomasWeller tried with the different table in database 5,06,011 object references in the list
Consuming approx 195 MegaBytes

Answer (score -1):

use `GC.Collect();` after clearing the list.

edit: try `FileProps=null;` instead clearing.

Comment: Same problem, memory not freed after GC.Collect also. Observing memory size consuming by application in Task Manager and also in VS Diagnostic Tool

Comment: Same problem after FileProps=null too